# Converting milliseconds to date

Tags: android, date

I am trying to save time in milliseconds in my database as text.

```
long time= System.currentTimeMillis()
```

After i am trying to retrieve it and convert to date like this:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor c = db.query("MovementTable", null, null, null, null, null, null);
String str = "";

long a = c.getLong(0);

if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        if (!c.getString(6).equals("0"))
        str = str + c.getLong(0) + " - " +c.getLong(1) + CheckPoint(new LatLng(c.getDouble(2),c.getDouble(3)))
                + " to " + CheckPoint(new LatLng(c.getDouble(4),c.getDouble(5))) + " " + c.getString(6) + "\n";
    } while (c.moveToNext());
}
c.close();

Text.setText(str);
dbHelper.close();
```

Code crashes then i am trying to initialize "a". But without it, it works. 
In string result is: 

`1433064363251 - 14330643544443`

What am i doing wrong? Please help. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`moveToFirst` method should be first, then you can access to Cursor values.

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    long a = c.getLong(0);
    do {
        if (!c.getString(6).equals("0"))
        str = str + c.getLong(0) + " - " +c.getLong(1) + CheckPoint(new LatLng(c.getDouble(2),c.getDouble(3)))
                + " to " + CheckPoint(new LatLng(c.getDouble(4),c.getDouble(5))) + " " + c.getString(6) + "\n";
    } while (c.moveToNext());
}
c.close();
```